# Invalid argument 'C:\\<forzen importlib._bootstrap>' when using logging in python

Tags: python, cx-freeze

When I try to use `cx_freeze` to generate exe, the exe file is correctly generated, but when I run the exe file I get this error :

```
File "C:\Python35\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1008 in __init__
StreamHandler.__init__(self, self.open())

File "C:\Python35\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1037 in _open

return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)

OSError : [Errno 22] Invalid argument:'C:\\frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

PS: i'm using the logging module to log some data in a file and the log path is `C:\`

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: i don't have access to source code, because i'm using a compiled library.